# How to remove "featured image" functionality from a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, post-thumbnails

I have made a custom post type for a child theme. I removed "thumbnail" from the supports array in functions.php and that prevents a featured image meta box from being displayed. However, when in the "add an image" modal dialogue thing, there is still a "Use as featured image" link. Why, oh why? More to the point, does anyone know how to remove?

I tried...

remove_post_type_support( 'itinerary', 'post-thumbnail' );

...where itinerary is the name of my custom post type. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Steve

Comment: see http://w4dev.com/wp/remove-featured-image-meta-box/ for a different approach which worked better for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some where in your theme you should have:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

Instead of removing support for a post type try only adding support for the post types you want:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post', 'movie' ) );
```

Comment: great that worked! I added 

add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post', 'page' ) ); 

to the child functions.php and called it by using this: 

add_action( 'init', 'mytheme_setup' ); 

function mytheme_setup() {
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post', 'page' ) );
}

so I didn't need to edit the parent theme :)

Thanks for your help Brady!

Steve

Answer (score 1):

To add to Brady's answer...

> `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post', 'movie' ) );`

If you only want to add support to a single post type, keep the `array()` in the declaration. With debugging turned on, if you declare `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', 'post' );` wordpress will complain that it is expecting an array when on the post edit page. So to enable Featured Images to only posts...

`add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post' ) );`

Answer (score 1):

A more modern approach is to use [`remove_post_type_support(post_type, 'thumbnail')`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_post_type_support/).

**Option #1:** Remove it immediately after creating your custom post type:

```
$args = []; //your args here

register_post_type('my_post_type', $args);

remove_post_type_support('my_post_type', 'thumbnail');
```

**Option #2:** Remove it from an existing post type:

```
function remove_thumbnail_support()
{
    remove_post_type_support('my_post_type', 'thumbnail');
}

add_action('init', 'remove_thumbnail_support', 11);
```